# Uploading file in API makes error 400

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm working on an API project which communicate with another API, my front is AngularJS

I try to upload a file (a picture) an post it through an API which already works for other posts (other posts are not uploads, just data)

I can upload the picture and treat it in a `formdata`, but when I try to post it, I have a 400 error with no '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`'. But my others post methods work well but this one makes trouble.

My Ajax post method:

```
apiDataService.postPicture = function(formData, callback) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiUrl + '/pictures',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': localStorageService.get('auth')
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // retrieve response data
        callback(response.data);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // an error occured
    });
};
```

I took the pattern of my others post methods so, it would works...

My uploading function:

```
self.addPicture = (image) => {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('the-file');
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    apiDataService.postPicture(formData);
}
```

And my view:

```
<form id="form-id">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <span>Image :</span>
        <br/>
        <input id="the-file" type="file" placeholder="Image du Procédé" ng-model="picture.file" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button ng-click="addPicture(image)">Enregistrer image</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

If you have any ideas, I don't understand my error...

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly due to your CORS options your server are using. Maybe you don't allow data header or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

@Nounnoune can you try to add below header I had Same Problem so I added below header and work like charm .

```
'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already many *Angular.js* modules to perform file uploading.

These two have explicit support for older browsers:

1. [Uses iframes as a fallback](https://github.com/leon/angular-upload)
2. [Uses FileAPI/Flash as a fallback](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a good form, a basic one only in HTML, it's not as pretty as I would like it to be, but it works! Just have to optimize it.